# How can I display instead download pdf file in express route

Tags: node.js, express, pdf, request

I'm doing a API request that sends a PDF file as response, but when the route is accessed, the file is immediately force downloaded. I just want to display a PDF file inside a client browser, without downloading it.

```
exports.print = (req,res) => {
    request("API").on('response', function(response) {
        res.set({
            'Content-Disposition': 'inline; filename=my.pdf',
            'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'
        });
    })
    .pipe(res);
}
```

Comment: Why not response.redirect to the pdf location this way browser will open the pdf?

Comment: because i've custom pdf viewer

Comment: And the pdf location, that i make request download the pdf file automatically